# Cursor near object detection

Tags: html, css

I have the following html:

```
<style>
   #menu-container
   {
       width: 100%;
       height: 40px;
       // used to detect hover 
   }

   .menu
   {
       border: 1px solid black;
       width: 300px;
       height: 20px;

       margin-top: -100px; // hidden
   }

   .menu-visible
   {
       margin-top: 0px; // visible
   }
</style>

<script>
   $("#menu-container").mouseenter(
       function()
       {
           $(".menu").toggleClass('menu-visible');
       }
   );
</script>

<div id="menu-container">
   <div class="menu">

   </div>
</div>
```

The menu-wrapper's height is +20px, that's the extra space I'm 'detecting' the motion on.

**Goal**: Menu has to show up when cursor is near the menu (not over it).

**Problem**: Everything is working great, except I can't click/interact with the content that is under the menu-container (the extra 20px space).

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: Give `overflow: hidden;` to `#menu-container`

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the same without javascript by doing the following:

```css
#menu-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  padding: 20px;
}
    
#menu-container:hover .menu {
  margin-top: 0px; // visible
}
        
.menu {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 300px;
  height: 20px;
  margin-top: -100px; // hidden
}
```

Preview here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KwRJoQ